# How Do I Write SAS Code to Open a Viewtable Window?

Tags: sas

I would like to write SAS code to open (and close) a viewtable window containing a dataset. Do you know of a way to do this?

All Best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DM` statement will programmatically issue Display Manager commands.  The commands your program will issue are

- `viewtable` opens the viewtable window
- `next` makes a window active
- `end` does various actions based on active window:

  - viewtable, closes the window
  - editor, submits the code
  - log, switches to editor

Sample code

Presume viewtable is open and subsequent code will be rebuilding the data set being viewed.  If the window is not closed the rebuild will fail because of the view table lock.

```
* close the window presumed to be open, releasing the lock;
dm 'next viewtable; end;';  

* rebuild the data set;
data work.have;
  set sashelp.cars(obs=10);
run;

* what hath I wrought ?;
* open a viewtable window and bring it to the top;
dm 'viewtable work.have' viewtable;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `DM` statement to execute display manager commands.  So you could use that to open a viewtable window.

```
dm "viewtable mylib.mytable";
```

You can also issue commands that could close the window, just make sure that you have moved focus to the right window.